# How do I cost out a homebew magic item: Mutex Bag Of Holding?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, homebrew

For the Pathfinder RPG, the costs and limits of a [Bag of Holding](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-of-holding/) are defined pretty clearly.
Though it comes in four different types, I'll take a Type I Bag of Holding as an example.  The Type I bag weighs
15 pounds, has a Contents Limit of 250 pounds., a Contents Volume Limit of 30 cubic feet, a Market Price of 2,500 gp, and a Cost To Create of 1,250 gp.  The creator needs the **Craft Wondrous Item** feat and the spell **Secret Chest**. Caster Level is 9.  The bag of holding opens into a nondimensional space.

For my campaign I've created a Mutex Bag of Holding. A Type I Mutex Bag of Holding is actually two different bags (A and B). Both bags open on to the same nondimensional space. Only one bag may be open at a time. If Bag A is already open, Bag B refuses to open and cannot be opened.

The advantage here is that Bag A can be across the globe from Bag B; it provides a way of resupplying a party from across vast distances, passing notes or potions or rations or whatever. Picking up and holding the bag does not provide any sort of identification, location nor communication with the owner of the other bag, but there's aways [Sending](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/sending/) spells. Passing notes through the bag is permitted.

**EDIT**   In case it is relevant, the Player Characters in my campaign currently have only one of the two bags and don't know who possesses the other bag: friend, foe, or absent-minded wizard who left Bag B open.

Does something like this already exist?  I have not found it in my searches to date.

How do I figure out the Cost To Create for this item?  I treat the two bags as one set.  I plan to put a premium on this because the pair allows some new creative uses over a single Bag, but I'm not sure how to cost this out, as it approaches the convenience of a [Teleportation Circle](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/teleportation-circle/) that is both permanent and portable.

---

Comment: "The two bags do not offer any communication..." What about passing notes? Presumably, I could put a diary into the bag and just write down any information I wanted to send to the other person.

Answer (score 13):

The [*ring gates*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/ring-gates/) are close to the item described:

> These always come in pairs—two iron rings, each about 18 inches in diameter. The rings must be on the same plane of existence and within 100 miles of each other to function. Whatever is put through one ring comes out the other, and up to 100 pounds of material can be transferred each day. (Objects only partially pushed through and then retracted do not count.) This useful device allows for instantaneous transport of items or messages, and even attacks. A character can reach through to grab things near the other ring, or even stab a weapon through if so desired. Alternatively, a character could stick his head through to look around. A spellcaster could even cast a spell through a ring gate. A Small character can make a DC 13 Escape Artist check to slip through. Creatures of Tiny, Diminutive, or Fine size can pass through easily. Each ring has an “entry side” and an “exit side,” both marked with appropriate symbols.

Normally, I wouldn't quote the entire description, but I wanted to demonstrate the *extreme* limits placed on this item compared to the item the question describes. And the *ring gates* cost 20,000 for a pair.

This GM wouldn't allow into his campaign a magic item exactly like the one the question describes. It's a world-changer, and maintaining verisimilitude after its introduction will be challenging unless the campaign's designed around it. This GM humbly recommends a per-day insert/extract weight limit similar to that of the *ring gates* equal to the *bag*'s typical capacity. Were that limitation added, a price of 10× the normal cost of a [*bag of holding*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-of-holding) of the same capacity may be reasonable. Absent that limitation, however, and this at least borders on a minor artifact as wide reproduction of such items obviates entire industries.

Comment: @fectin It's kind of the difference between hiring a dude to do something for you and having a machine that does it for you, except in this case every couple of days a new dude—who is a potentially violent extradimensional creature—must be hired by a 9th-level wizard… and the machine is magic sack. I think, long run, advantage: magic sack.

Comment: @HeyICanChan: Would it be helpful perhaps to impose restrictions on when the bag may be opened or closed, e.g. saying that one side must be continuously closed for a certain length of time before the other can be opened?

Comment: @supercat Possibly? I mean, I'd have to know specifics, but it's not really *time* that's important but *volume*. Saying such a *bag* can only be opened for 5 min. before it must be closed for 5 min. still doesn't save the jobs of countless couriers, stevedores, ship captains, traveling merchants, etc. Now, if we're talking something like *Once per day the* bag *can teleport its contents to another* bag *to which the first is linked* then we may have a deal. I still think it may be a Tippyverse-style game-changer if mass produced, though.

Comment: @HeyICanChan: I was thinking in terms of something like hours; the time could be fixed, or it could depend upon distance (so the system would be something like a pneumatic delivery tube.  Put something in and close an end, and then some time later the other end may be opened to retrieve the item).  Possible subjects for discussion are whether items may be recalled (and how quickly) and whether more than two bags might be linked.

Answer (score 3):

So, it sounds like this works exactly like two different wizards using the same target for *secret chest*. I would cost it like two spells, at will. That's 2x(9x5x50), plus 5000 for the focus (not doubled). That's 9500, so maybe bump the minimum CL to 10, which moves the price up to 10,000 gold and gives it an even 10 cubic feet.

Wizards already have this in a non-permanent way just by wanting it, so you may as well let non-casters have nice things too.

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions here. One question is : how much should it cost to create this item? The other is: how much can you sell one half of it for?

This item could be used for two-way trade between two cities, so we might estimate its cost as similar to that of two permanent teleportation circles -- so, 47000gp.  The teleportation circles are fixed to one place, but they have higher throughput than the bag, so maybe it balances out.

However, one half of the item is basically useless: it's like a normal bag of holding except someone can steal your stuff. No NPC should be willing to buy this.

I assume you're planning to use this as a plot trigger: the npc tries to buy the bag, and one or both sides potentially try to backstab the other?

Comment: I'm not sure how much my players read this site.  Assuming they read it "Very Little:" My current intent is that an unknown benefactor fills the bag with small items of use, but occasionally leaves her bag open, rendering the bag in the players' possession inoperative.  Given how much potential this has to change the campaign in ways I did not realize at first, the bag may not last very long and burn out.