# Homebrewing a 2-way Bag of Holding: price & balance

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, crafting, homebrew-review

Our DM has decided that it only makes sense for a two-way [Bag of Holding](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-of-holding/) to exist in our world.

**Background:** Our characters own a small shipping company that frequently makes its profits by selling things our party finds in dungeons, and splits the profit with us. Frequently this means that we have to travel back to town or even track down an active boat and intercept it mid-route in order to drop off more wholesale goods. For reasons I'm not going to get into, we don't really want to go through this process with any other merchants.

Obviously the process is a pain and requires some form of scrying and teleportation every time, or worse, hunting down traders and intercepting them (because again, we only trust this one trader).

The DM has ruled that the trader will make a two-way Bag of Holding, which is to say, one dimensional space to be accessed from two separate bags, which are forever linked, in order to reasonably deposit items directly to the trader in exchange for money. We payed 20,000 gold for this to be researched by a magician and subsequently created, (presumably 10,000 gold for each task, estimated by DM).

**My questions are as follows:** using the existing Pathfinder system of rules,  **a)** are there ways this could be overpowered we haven't considered? **b)** is this a reasonable price with consideration to item creation feats that would be involved (presumably a [gate spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/gate/) with permanency inside the hole is probably the most expensive way to produce such an object, but I suspect there's cheaper methods).

**Additional information:**
The only other balancing rule we have is that air doesn't explicitly enter the hole unless both entrances are open, to prevent people from staying inside it with the safe side of the portal open.

For price, assume the bag of holding for all intents and purposes is a type I Bag of Holding, only with two openings, one on each side.

Comment: First thing I thought of when you asked about overpowered: I'd conceal a two-ways bag somewhere, drop a portable hole in the other bag. The portable hole tears apart the dimensional space of the two-ways bags, creating two rifts to the astral plane and you just created a very convoluted remote actionned bomb. Might want to rule how it exactly plays out on the edge case of the normal bag of holding (which you already did regarding the air inside the bag, so kudo on that)

Comment: @Nyakouai good point, but for 20,000 gold + the price of a portable hole, I feel like you can probably already buy something better than a remote controlled bomb; see: amulet of fireball

Comment: @ErinB For that price, I think you could make an intelligent Necklace of Fireballs that activates itself.

Comment: @Axoren I'm concerned about the moral ramifications of making an intelligent magical item detonate pieces of itself, but I love the way you think!

Comment: True, true. But it's a professional habit, it's a good habit to define the weird use cases people are going to come up with. Especially in games, given the numbers of questions we ask here about not well defined cases.

Comment: This is a common use of [Ring Gates](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/r-z/ring-gates/). Ring Gates, though, have a base cost of 40,000gp, only function within 100 miles of each other, and have a limit on the amount of goods that can be passed through each day. Based on that, I'd probably up the price, but its not game-breaking. Also, personally, just to stop physics weirdness around why air can't move through an opening but solid objects can, I'd say only one bag can access the space at a time. The other bag just becomes an ordinary bag at those times.

Comment: @NathanMiller that seems like a great answer, if you want to write that up a bit more and submit it as one?

Comment: [A surprisingly similar question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105552/8610)

Comment: @HeyICanChan That is *remarkably* similar hahaha.

Comment: @HeyICanChan darn, I searched for a while and couldn't find anything; didn't think about using the word "Mutex"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common use of [Ring Gates](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/r-z/ring-gates). Ring Gates, though, have a few limitations it sounds like your Bags of Holding don't:

- Only function within 100 miles of each other (and on the same plane, if that comes into play)
- Up to 100lbs of material can be passed through each day
- Small creatures can pass through with an Escape Artist check, smaller can pass through freely

My initial reaction is your bags should be priced higher... but they also have some benefits your linked bags don't have:

- Attacks can be made through the gates
- Spells can be cast through the gates

This *might* balance them out, but that's really going to be a DM judgment call.

Also, personally, just to stop physics weirdness around why air can't move through an opening but solid objects can, I'd have only one bag access the space at a time. The other bag just becomes an ordinary bag at those times. I will also now think of them as Schrodinger's Bags of Might-Be-Holding, because who knows if the trader has emptied it yet or not?

Comment: Great answer! This is exactly what I was looking for! A reference to another or spell and restrictions relating to the analogous object! Thanks for writing this up!

Answer (score 1):

## Free teleportation

Anyone small enough can climb through the bag.  If the bag solves the problem for furniture and art pieces as well as small knickknacks, that means presumably anyone Medium or smaller can get through the bag without even an escape artist check, and Large and maybe even Huge creatures can make it through with an appropriate (DC 30) Escape Artist check.

Provided the bag remains open, this means people can travel from one place to another via the bag any number of times per day without issue.  If the shipping company keeps the bag in its headquarters, for example, your party can travel back (or, more reasonably, all but one of them can travel back, so someone still has the other end) and hang out in town instead of camping in the dungeon.  This means not only can you *sell* goods efficiently, but you can also *acquire* them.

This isn't necessarily a problem-- the item is being priced very high and the effect doesn't really cause problems so much as speed up the game-- but it is a significant consequence.

Comment: good answer, although I feel like the team leaving one person behind in a dungeon is probably worse than the whole team camping out in the same spot

Comment: @ErinB *rope trick* is a thing.